# after case go back to all options

Tags: c#

maybe there is an easy answer but I'm not finding it i hope you guys ca help with my question

```
String herhaal;
 do
 {
    int caseSwitch = 1;
    WagenPark wagenPark = new WagenPark();

    Console.WriteLine("*** Wagenpark beheer ***");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Voeg een wagen toe");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Geef wagenpark overzicht");
    caseSwitch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    switch (caseSwitch)
    {
        case 1:
            Wagen wagen = new Wagen();
            Console.WriteLine("Geef de nummerplaat van de wagen in: ");
            wagen.NummerPlaat = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Geef het merk van de wagin in: ");
            wagen.Merk = Console.ReadLine();
            wagenPark.schrijfWagenIn(wagen);
            Console.WriteLine("Wagen met nummerplaat " + wagen.NummerPlaat + " is toegevoegd.");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("*** Wagenpark overzicht ***");
            wagenPark.geefOverzicht();
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Default case");
            break;

    }
        Console.WriteLine("Wens je nog een keuze te maken op het menu (J/N) ?");
        herhaal = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (herhaal == "J" || herhaal == "j");
 }
```

at the end of each one of the case's the programm should go back to the 2 options i have in the top

```
Console.WriteLine("*** Wagenpark beheer ***");
Console.WriteLine("1. Voeg een wagen toe");
Console.WriteLine("2. Geef wagenpark overzicht");
```

but after case 1 it just ands the same with case 2 I thought the do while would prevent this but it doesn't.

Comment: Does the code reach the point where it is asking  you if you want to make another choice?

Comment: What do you mean by "after case 1 it just ands"?

Comment: Each time through the loop, you do `WagenPark wagenPark = new WagenPark();` - was it not your intention to have a single one of these and add *multiple* `Wagen` to it? (And, of course, in case 2 you're working with a new one that hasn't had a `Wagen` added to it)

Comment: You need to clearly state what the problem is.  Though @Damien_The_Unbeliever probably has the best guess so far.

Comment: You already have a `do...while` around the switch, so why not step through in your debugger and see what happens?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i put it outside the loop and it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analysing your code, there are two things that can result in an unexpected behaviour.

The first one is as stated by **@Damien_The_Unbeliever** in the [comments to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043728/after-case-go-back-to-all-options#comment55842258_34043728). You create a new car park (`WagenPark`) each time you go through the `do...while` loop. As a result of this, you will not have more than one car (`Wagen`) checked in simply because you have replaced the `wagenPark` with a new `wagenPark`. This issue can be solved by moving the `wagenPark` initialization to the point *before* the loop starts.

```
WagenPark wagenPark = new WagenPark(); // put it here
do
{
    int caseSwitch = 1;
    WagenPark wagenPark = new WagenPark(); // delete this

    Console.WriteLine("*** Wagenpark beheer ***");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Voeg een wagen toe");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Geef wagenpark overzicht");
    caseSwitch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

The next potential error is that the method for checking-in the cars (`WagenPark.schrijfWagenIn()`) is not working properly. Possibly, the method for giving the overview (`WagenPark.geefOverzicht()`) could also not be working properly. Test these two methods to make sure that they work properly and your code will be okay.